# How to query latest value of large amount of devices that are all aligned in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, sequence-alignment, apache-iotdb, iotdb

```
IoTDB> select last * from root.station01.cell.bms01.bunch01.** limit 10 align by device;  
Msg: 701: Last query doesn't support align by device.
```

I tried this statement in Apache IoTDB:  `select last * from root.station01.cell.bms01.bunch01.** limit 10 align by device`, and got this error: Msg: 701: Last query doesn't support align by device.
Seems like query align by device do not support querying the latest data value for each device? If so, how do I query the latest value of each device if I have hundreds of device nodes? My device time series are all aligned and all collected at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your goal in Apache IoTDB:

1. `select max_time(any time series under the device), last_value(*) from root.station01.cell.bms01.bunch01.** limit 10 align by device`;
2. `select last * from root.station01.cell.bms01.bunch01.** limit 10`;

The second method returns the time series overview. You can add `order by timeseries`, then the timeseries in the same device will be returned together, then the upper layer will do the processing.